# Is LIBKML being actively developed?

Tags: kml, google-earth, google

According to the page on Google Code (https://code.google.com/p/libkml/downloads/list), the last update was Feb 2010.

Is this library still being updated?

Answer (score 1):

Please see active development efforts in [github.com/libkml/libkml](https://github.com/libkml/libkml)

The question of why it forked was answered in the readme. To simply put, the idea was to keep it active one way or another. The project has now successfully packaged into debian and also used in used in gdal/ogr libkml driver. you can download latest release from [releases](https://github.com/libkml/libkml/releases).

Full disclaimer: I am maintaining this fork.